# Apt-get update failed to fetch Ubuntu Server 20.04 Raspberry Pi 3 b+

Tags: apt, server, 20.04, updates

[CLOSED]

I'm using ubuntu server 32bit 20.04 on Raspberry pi 3 b+.
When I try to install mariadb-server this is the output

```
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Name or service not known
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.28+maria~bionic) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I tried to update with `sudo apt-get update` but this is the output:

```
    sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Name or service not known
Hit:1 http://sgp1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.3/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

That's all. Thanks for help!

Comment: I see multiple problems. First, you have a network problem ("*network is unreachable*"). Second, you are installing a package that is available in the Ubuntu repositories (name: `mariadb-server`), but you're using a third-party repo instead. Third, you're trying to install  a Bionic (18.04) version of that non-Ubuntu package, which is why likely you are getting the "*impossible situation*" error. Advice: Once you get your network figured out, delete the non-Ubuntu the source and simply install the Ubuntu package.

Comment: 1-For communicate with my raspberry I'm using ssh so network should work. 2- I'm trying to install mariadb-server like you said so I can't find the error. 3-I'm using ethernet. 4- How can I delete the non-Ubuntu source?

Comment: "*network should work*"; irrelevant -- your own output says you have a network problem of some kind. If you still have it and aren't sure how to troubleshoot it, open a new question. (or use the Search box at the top of the page).

Comment: How you delete a source depends upon how you added the source. Looks like you were following some kind of instructions, but you did not provide a link. Please provide one in your question. Were it my system, I would have done *absolutely nothing* to any settings, nor used any commands before `sudo apt update` to update the package database, and then `sudo apt install mariadb-server` to install the actual database server. Everything previous to those steps is what you must undo.

Comment: Ok. I'll reset all and re-install ubuntu server cause I think undoing all is a waste of time. Thanks for help if I'll meet this problem again I'll tell u. Thank for the help